# Limit number of list items to be displayed in List expression

Tags: javascript, mustache, ractivejs

I have a requirement of displaying a `list array` in two divs, first half in first DIV and second half list in second DIV. Please not that I don't want to splice the list array in two parts and display them in two lists.

Here is the template I have, for example

```
<!-- First half number of items should be displayed in firstHalf div -->
<div id="firstHalf">
   {{#each names:i}}
      {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
<!-- Second half number of items should be displayed in secondHalf div -->
<div id="secondHalf">
   {{#each names:i}}
      {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

For example If I have data like below

```
var data = [ {
    firstName : "Joe", lastName: "Armstrong"
}, {
    firstName : "Jose", lastName: "Valim"
}];
```

It needs to be rendered like below

```
<div id="firstHalf">
   Joe Armstrong
</div>
<div id="firstHalf">
   Jose Valim
</div>
```

Please give me suggestions to proceed further.

Comment: Can you split it into two lists before sending it to mustache?

Comment: @p.s.w.g If I split the problem is, I have two way binding for the data. I need to make extra calculations to update actual data of the model. To avoid that I don't want to split into two lists.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure; I'm really not familiar with mustache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another valid approach would be to reference list members indirectly, via an index reference. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/VGjGH/) we're generating a range of indices, and then referring to `list[this]`:

```
<!-- First half number of items should be displayed in firstHalf div -->
<div id="firstHalf">
   {{#each range(0,names.length/2) }}
      {{names[this].firstName}} {{names[this].lastName}}
   {{/each}}
</div>

<!-- Second half number of items should be displayed in secondHalf div -->
<div id="secondHalf">
   {{#each range(names.length/2,names.length) }}
      {{names[this].firstName}} {{names[this].lastName}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

The `range()` function just looks like this:

```
function ( start, end ) {
    var arr = [];
    for ( i = Math.floor(start); i < Math.floor(end); i += 1 ) {
        arr.push( i );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Even though there's a perfectly good solution from pseudosavant, I'm mentioning this because indirectly referencing elements is a useful trick to have up your sleeve when doing things like two-way binding with tabular data.

Comment: Accepted this solution as this is better in many ways than my solution in pseudosavant's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mustache is logic less, and if you do not provide two arrays, you cannot split the entries in two divs.

When the template is rendered each occurring `{{key}}` is substituted with the same value,  for each element in the list.

For this you could probably use handlebars.

Comment: No way to write any expression in {{#each names:i | i < names.length/2 }} like this?

Comment: No, not with mustache.

Comment: I am using RactiveJS, any way to do the same without disturbing two way data binding using RactiveJS?

Comment: I am not familiar with reactive, but can't you just create a new array for mustache and do not touch the original one? Mustache will create a string and not change the input array, so even references wont be a problem in this case.

Comment: I settled down with a dirty solution pasted here http://pastie.org/9415897 . Is that suggestible?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it by iterating over the list twice in a template and still only using one array. Just use a conditional in each iteration to to the first or second half of the list.

#### Template has two sections: one for each half

```
<div id="firstHalf">
    {{#each names:i}}
        {{#if i < names.length / 2}} // Conditional to only display first half of `names`
            {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
<div id="secondHalf">
    {{#each names:i}}
        {{#if i > names.length / 2}} // Conditional to only display second half of `names`
            {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Inspired by code from here: http://pastie.org/9415897#

Comment: I settled down with a dirty solution pasted here http://pastie.org/9415897 . Is that suggestible?

Comment: That looks similar. I didn't realize you could calculate the conditional inline like that.

Comment: Please paste my code as part of your answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Exception which code are you talking about? The code at that pastie.org link?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Exception have you actually tried the code at that pastie.org link? I don't think it actually works. I can't get syntax like that to work with Mustache/Handlebars. The code I posted does though.

Comment: I have used it with RactiveJS which internally uses Mustache. It worked in my project and I am using it happily.

Comment: @Exception Cool. I updated it. Does RactiveJS use a vanilla Mustache template engine? I'll have to look into that.